# Controller configuration for NBA 2K21 on Stadia

Tags: nba2k21, stadia

I just bought NBA 2K21 on Stadia and have played it but have these questions, and I wonder if you know the answer to any of them:

1. How can I **configure non-standard Stadia controller**? (It’s confusing when the screen prompts me to press the Stadia button or the ☰ and I don’t know what the equivalent is on my controller, which doesn't have those buttons.)
2. How can I learn **which buttons** do what in NBA 2K21 (such as double-team or alleyoop)?
3. Are there any **replays** during online multiplayer? How?

Comment: Hey Ryan, welcome back to Arqade. We've closed out your question since it technically contains 3 questions. Your tags exist now, so if you'd like to split your questions our into multiples, that would be your best bet now!